# VBA Windows().Activate Non-Excel File Window

Tags: excel, vba

This might sound like a relatively simple question, but I cannot figure it out.

Using VBA how can I activate a specific window and then close it? For example, if I have a text file open called *test.txt* how can I activate it and then close it? I've tried:

```
Windows("test.txt").Activate       
ActiveWindow.Close
```

and receive below error message when VBA attempts to process the first line:

> Rune-time error '9': Subscript our of range

Comment: Are you trying to do this with any window, or the text/notepad specifically?

Comment: You're getting that error because the `Application.Windows` collection contains no element keyed with `test.txt`. Wouldn't you rather want to work with the `Workbooks` collection though? How are you opening that file?

Comment: If the window is already open and you are merely trying to get it's handle so you can close it using code, you would want to use an `API` call named `FindWindow` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @braX I think OP is merely trying to close a file they've opened in Excel. Seeing how they opened the file (i.e. whether they have an object reference pointing to the corresponding workbook object) would shed some light about how it could be closed (e.g. `book.Close SaveChanges:=False`). I don't think there's a need to dive into Win32 stuff here.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The "test.txt" was just a simplified example, but guess I should elaborate a bit further. I have a macro that that opens a different program called STAAD.pro. The macro instructions STAAD.pro to run an analysis and save the results. Once in a while, this STAAD.pro produces an error message. This error message stalls up STAAD.pro and the macro. I'd like to simply close the error message box that appears but cannot find a way to do so.

Comment: The "test.txt" was a misleading example.